# How do I select a region that has been syntax highlighted?

Tags: elisp, syntax-highlighting

In a buffer with source code that has already been syntax highlighted (eg some Python code in python-mode), how do I access the results of the syntax parsing to select text from elisp that is a particular syntax?

For example if I want to select the next keyword, or select all of the current comment around the point, or all of the string around point.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the string around point:

```
(defun my-string-atpt ()
  "Hightlight string at point. "
  (interactive)
  (let ((pps (parse-partial-sexp (point-min) (point))))
    (when
    (nth 3 pps)
      (goto-char (nth 8 pps))
      (set-mark (point))
      (forward-sexp))))
```

Comment at point might start that way:

```
(defun my-comment-atpt ()
  "Highlight comment at point. "
  (interactive)
  (let ((pps (parse-partial-sexp (point-min) (point))))
    (when
    (nth 4 pps)
      (goto-char (nth 8 pps))
      (set-mark (point))...
```

However, as `(nth 4 pps)` is reliable only WRT current line, needs a loop still to detect the beginning of a commented section, likewise the end.

A complete implemention as `ar-comment-atpt` should exist there:

https://github.com/andreas-roehler/werkstatt/blob/master/thing-at-point-utils.el

Select the next item fontified as keyword like this:

```
(defun my-next-font-lock-keyword-face ()
  (interactive)
  (while (and (not (eobp)) (forward-char 1) (not (eq (face-at-point) 'font-lock-keyword-face))))
  (when (eq (face-at-point) 'font-lock-keyword-face)
    (set-mark (point))
    (while (eq (face-at-point) 'font-lock-keyword-face)
      (forward-char 1))))
```

Comment: Thanks! Having read the documentation for `parse-partial-sexp`, I can see that it will be very useful for what I'm trying to do!